# "Write append" options bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on bigquery with standard sql and I have the following problem.
I am transforming a table with millions of data, but I will only work with the data of yesterday and today.

The result of that query (which is already listed) I have to store in another table.
The problem is that what must be executed every 1 hour and when creating the scheduled query and placing the option of "write append", the data that has been previously saved will be duplicated.
I need something like "write to table if it does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your scheduled query written with replace in mind:

```
REPLACE TABLE `dataset.mytable` 
AS 
SELECT 1;
```

this way you fully replace on each run.

**Update:**
You may use MERGE statement to skip existing rows and add only new ones.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I misspelled my problem, I need to "attach" the result of the scheduled query, but only the data that is not in the new table.

Comment: then use a MERGE statement where you can skip existing rows, and update/or add new rows

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views are appending only new data.

They can query only single table, support only a [limited set](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#supported_mvs) of aggregation functions (APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT, ARRAY_AGG, AVG, COUNT, HLL_COUNT.INIT, MAX, MIN, SUM) and do not support a computation on top of an aggregation but maybe they will fit your use case.